# Flash Builder 4.6/Flex String unserialize

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, serialization, builder

I got a string like

```
a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:19:"http://www.test.com";s:5:"value";d:2.20;}}
```

and I need to unserialize it to an Array using AS3 or Flash Builder 4.6/Flex

How could i do the job?

I cannot unserialize and convert to XML using PHP.

In few words I need to do the same as [PHP unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) but with Flash Builder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an OpenSource for this [SerializerClass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/serializerclass/files/serializerclass%20ActionScript%203/)

```
var string = 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:19:"http://www.test.com";s:5:"value";d:2.20;}}';
import org.sepy.io.Serializer;
var myData = Serializer.unserialize( string ); 
trace(myData[0]['name']);
```